# Set Previous and next for the posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, singlepage

```
<?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<h1><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) .'">' .$recent["post_title"].'</a> </h1> ';
  }
?>
```

I added this code for getting just single latest post on desired page.

How can I add next and previous button of posts to it?

Comment: It depends - what would you consider the "next" or "previous" post? Is it from **all posts**? Or within a category? Or .... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `previous post` link, You can do it using following code:

```
<?php $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true ); ?>
 <?php if ( is_a( $prev_post, 'WP_Post' ) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $prev_post->ID ); ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

If you want to get `next post` link, Than:

```
<?php $next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false ); ?>
 <?php if ( is_a( $next_post, 'WP_Post' ) ) {  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $next_post->ID ); ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

You can check more information about this function here : [get_adjacent_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post)

Comment: This is a nice method.

Answer (score 0):

```
             $previous=$recent["ID"]-1;
             echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($previous) . '">' .   PREVIOUS.'</a> '; 

             $next=$recent["ID"]+1;
             echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($next) . '">' .   NEXT.'</a> ';
```

I did this and it worked :)